# Mirror image along y axis

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, mirror

I would like to mirror an image along the y-axis 
This is the code that i have:

```
for(int i = 0;i <breite; i ++){
           for(int j = 0; j <hoehe; j++){
                int temp = getRGB(breite-1-i,j);
                setRGB(breite-1-i,j,getRGB(i,j));
                setRGB(i,j,temp);

                   }}
```

In theory it should work, if I did not mix something up (which i probably did).
After i run the code, the picture still remains the same.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: I want to flip it vertically. But it doesn`t flip at all, it just remains the same

Comment: Your image isn't symmetric, is it?

Comment: oh, you need to stop once you get halfway through, as it is you're swapping every pair twice and ending up with what you started with. I think.

Comment: Of course! How could i not think of this..
Thank you very much!

Comment: Also, I think you'll need a `repaint()` at some point, if you're not already doing that.

Comment: Yeah, I did that in another method, it works fine now :)

Comment: @genisage You could post that as an answer, since it's obviously what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

Almost right... But you only need to iterate the for-loop for breite/2, else you mirror it twice and you wont see any change.

`for(int i = 0; i <breite/2; i++); 
    for(int j = 0; j<hoehe; j++){
       int temp = getRGB(breite-1-i,j);
       setRGB(breite-1-i,j,getRGB(i,j));
       setRGB(i,j,temp);
       }
}`